# Matrices and orders

Tags: matrices

Is there any formula to calculate the number of all possible matrices of order 3×3 with each number 0 or 3 ? Or a general formula for any order of a matrix ?

Comment: All elements should be 0?

Comment: Each number can be 0 or 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In m*n matrix.

m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns.

**(Number of options)$^{m*n}$** for all possible matrices.

In your case m= 3 and n = 3.

And each element can be 0 or 3. So number of options 2.

Number of possible matrices = $(2)^{3*3} = {2}^9$

Comment: Try this method to different order of matrices. Start with small order matrices.

Comment: Ok thank you for helping ☺

Comment: Mine pleasure..

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrices. $A$ has entries $a_{ij}$, with $a_{ij}$ being $0$ or $n$. The total number of matrices is therefore $2^{(n^2)}.$

Comment: Is it true even if the numbers are other than 0 or n ?